# Django - problems with Grappelli, mptt and sorting fields

Tags: django, django-mptt, mptt, django-grappelli

I am using Grappelli admin for it's great sortable fields function. However, I don't seem to be able to get it to work with mptt. Here's my code:

```
class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(category)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True,related_name='subitems')
        position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Position")

        class Meta:
                ordering = ['position']

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.title
```

this is my admin:

```
from content.models import *
from django.contrib import admin

class ItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Item
    fields = ('title', 'parent', 'position')
    sortable_field_name = "position"

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Category
    inlines = (ItemInline, )

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

and finally here's my template:

```
<ul>
    {% recursetree nodes %}
        <li>
            {{ node.title }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

The problem is, if I use `class Item(models.Model):` in my models the admin functions just fine, sortable and all, but my template fails, saying

> type object 'MenuItems' has no attribute '_mptt_meta'

and when I use `class MenuItems(MPTTModel):` everything goes other way around; my template works ok but I can't order the fields in my admin ("position" number changes, but nothing else, it still lists items in their original order.

So, I was wondering if anyone knows whether it's possible to get these two things to work together at all, or do I just need to try to find another way...

Thanks!